# How to apply animations to items in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am new to HTML, CSS and JS/jQuery. I'm creating a test website just to get familiar with jQuery and can't seem to figure an issue out.

I have a navigation bar at the top of the page which contains a logo on the left and links on the right. I've set up the below jQuery code to fade the links in and out upon mouse enter/leave:

```
$(document).ready(main);

function main() {
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    /* pauseOnHover: true */
  })

  $('.nameorlogo, .navitems').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.nameorlogo').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.navitems').fadeTo('fast', 1);
  })

  $('.nameorlogo, .navitems').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.nameorlogo').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    $('.navitems').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
  })
};
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSTest1</title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../js/jquery-3.2.0.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../js/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../js/marquee.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class=topheader>
        <nav class=navtop>
            <div class=nameorlogo>
                <h1><a href="index.html">JSTest1</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class=navitems>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class=marquee>This is a test for JavaScript</div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is when I hover over a link, either nav links or the logo, everything fades in and out, I want them all to be independant.

I know you can do this in CSS, this is purely to help me learn and understand.

Thanks for your help.

Jim

Comment: Just FYI you should always wrap attribute values in quotes. While it may work without, you're asking for a headache if you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add them in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the the `this` keyword like `$(this)` to refer to the *currently hovered item*

```
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

Also, notice that `.navitems` is the whole UL element, while you need to target the LI elements. Therefore

```
$('.nameorlogo, .navitems li').mouseenter(function()
```

Additionally here's other similar ways to achieve what you desire:

### using `.on()` method

```js
$('.nameorlogo, .navitems li').on({
  mouseenter : function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
  },
  mouseleave : function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0.5);
  },
});
// .stop() is here to prevent animation buildups
```

```css
.nameorlogo,
.navitems li{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=nameorlogo>
    <h1><a href="index.html">JSTest1</a></h1>
</div>
<div>
    <ul class=navitems>
        <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Using `.hover()` method

```js
$('.nameorlogo, .navitems li').hover(function(evt) {
  var isMouEnt = evt.type === "mouseenter";
  $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, isMouEnt ? 1 : 0.5);
});
// .stop() is here to prevent animation buildups
```

```css
.nameorlogo,
.navitems li{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=nameorlogo>
    <h1><a href="index.html">JSTest1</a></h1>
</div>
<div>
    <ul class=navitems>
        <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added this in. The logo now works independently, but the navigation bar still highlights everything

Comment: I've added in the suggested changes, the logo is still working properly, however the navigation links, when I hover over them, it is fading in both the logo and the links, I'm hoping to get the logo, and all 4 links working independantly. Strangely as well, when hovering over the navigation links, they are going more opaque rather than fading to 1

Comment: Hopefully my last edit will clear some thoughts @JHiggins

Comment: That's working now :) Thank you. Just another quick one, I've noticed that if I run the mouse over the links quickly, it's almost like it needs to catch up, the animation keeps running, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @JHiggins by simply prefixing `.fadeTo` with `.stop()` like `$(this).stop().fadeTo(`...